# Kotlin: Mobile: setOnClickListener all buttons have to be double clicked instead of single click

Tags: android, kotlin

I currently am learning how to code with pretty a combination of basic java tutorials, then converting the process to Kotlin.  I have made an app that does 3 things, it sends a string to a second screen to use in a sentence, and lastly it closes the app. However the buttons require two presses and I do not know why.

Below are my xml's and my kt files. Any input would be helpful.

***Manifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gmail.launch">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".launch2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***Main Activity.kt***

```
package com.gmail.launch

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun sendMessage (view: View){
        val nameb = findViewById<Button>(R.id.namebtn)
                val namet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nametext)

        nameb.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, launch2::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("com.gmail.launch.name",namet.text.toString())

            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun openGoogle (view: View) {
        val gglB = findViewById<Button>(R.id.gglbtn)
        gglB.setOnClickListener {
            val googleURL  =   Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            googleURL.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/")
            startActivity(googleURL)
        }
    }

    fun closeButton (view: View) {
        val closeB = findViewById<Button>(R.id.CloseB)
        closeB.setOnClickListener {
            finishAffinity()

        }
    }
}
```

***MainActivity.xml file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gglbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="openGoogle"
        android:text="Open Google"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namebtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/namebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nametext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nametext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/namebtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CloseB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="157dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="156dp"
        android:onClick="closeButton"
        android:text="Close App"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gglbtn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Launch2.kt***

```
package com.gmail.launch

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class launch2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch2)
        val nameE = intent.getStringExtra("com.gmail.launch.name")
        val txtV = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtV)
        txtV.text = nameE.plus(" is a giant nerd!")

    }
}
```

***Launch2.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".launch2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You're mixing two different ways to set `OnClickListener`s. Either use the `android:onClick` attribute in the layout XML, _or_ use `setOnClickListener()` in the code, in `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`. Don't try to do both.

Comment: The above is completely correct.  I have now commented out the 'onClickListener' and it immediately solved the issue.  Thank you very much.  On a weird note, I found a convoluted way to set double click requirement, that should never be used. That is the answer, i just wish i could mark it as such.  Thank you Mike M.

Answer (score 0):

Mike M. Got it right above but it looks like his answer is not markable as an answer.

You're mixing two different ways to set OnClickListeners. Either use the android:onClick attribute in the layout XML, or use setOnClickListener() in the code, in onCreate(), after setContentView(). Don't try to do both. -Mike M.